# jQuery CSS Opacity on focus issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, focus, opacity

I have a div which contains navigation items, along with a text input (which will be used as a search bar). When the user hovers over the navigation div, the opacity changes from 0.6 to 1 using CSS and then back again when the user moves their mouse away.

I want to use either CSS or jQuery to keep the opacity at 1 if the search input is in focus whether or not the user is hovering over the navigation bar. I have tried using a simple if function (my knowledge of jQuery isn't great):

```
if ($("#navsearchbox").is(":focus")){
  $("#navbar").css('opacity', '1');
}
```

This probably works in the sense that it is being appended when the search input is first focused on, but I guess as soon as the user moves their mouse away from the navigation div the CSS might be overriding that?

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I have almost got this working by using jQuery to control the hover opacity for the navbar div, but how do I set up a jQuery function that will detect if the navbarsearch input is not in focus?

Comment: This is in an event handler, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but try this:

```
$("#navsearchbox").focus(function(event){
  $("#navbar").css('opacity', '1');
}).blur(function(event){
  $("#navbar").css('opacity', '0.5');
});
```

Comment: EDIT: Actually, after this has been run, it is stopping the hover css opacity from working when the user hovers over the navbar. This is the css I'm using:

        #navbar:hover { opacity: 1; }

Maybe I should use jQuery for this too?

Comment: That is correct, the CSS `:hover` pseudo selector has very spotty cross-browser compatibility. [See more info here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: I've managed to get this working by using jQuery to control the hover opacity on the navbar as well. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a CSS selector `:focus` you can use instead of jQuery:

```
#navsearchbox:focus #navbar
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This removes the need for any javascript.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for adding that :). If the OP needs IE7< support then resort to jQuery.

Comment: I've tried this before but unfortunately it doesn't work, I think the css that controls the navbar opacity is overriding this css when the user moves the mouse out of the navbar

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the fadeTo() jquery function?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myField" value="Here is some">​
```

CSS

```
#myField {
    opacity:0.5;
}​
```

jQuery

```
$("#myField").focus(function(event){
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
}).blur(function(event){
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
});​
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YMK7/)

More info here : [jQuery fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

Comment: This works, but not in the context that I am working with, sorry.